# pass array to the puppet resource defined

Tags: puppet

I would like to test if multiple packages exist in my environment or not, based on this test I would like to generate the final catalog.

```
if !defined( Package[ 'apache2' ] ) {
    package { 'apache2':
        ensure  => installed,
    }
}
if !defined( Package[ 'libapache2-svn' ] ) {
    package { 'libapache2-svn':
        ensure  => installed,
    }
}
```

In future I would like to control in the following way:

```
Package { ensure => "installed" }
$packageList = [ 'apache2', 'libapache2-svn' ]

if !defined( Package[ $packageList ] ) {
    package { $packageList: }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: also.. note that `defined()` does not check to see if a package is installed on your system or not. It checks to see if a `package` resource for that particular package is in the puppet catalog. Even if ensure is set to `absent`, it should still return true.

Comment: I understand the concept of catalog. But I am getting error when I pass array of elements in the defined resource. My objective is to loop multiple elements through the defined resource.

Comment: you mean the `defined` `function` not `resource`. and the function doesnt appear to accept an array argument. https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/functions/defined.rb

Comment: This is generally a Bad Idea. See https://github.com/ffrank/puppet-constraints#defined for the reasoning and an alternative approach.